# Is All Time filter in a dashboard necessary?

Tags: dashboard, filter, administration

I know putting an ALL TIME filter allows me to view all the data from the start to the present. But how really is important to me to allow viewing all of it and how it cant affect my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selecting presets in the time filter must depend on user needs and you should find a way to do it with affordable technology, if it's not very needed or frequently used you can send it by mail or do it on cheaper slower servers.
most of services set time for data retention.

Comment: (Does) But All time relates to default presentation of all items/lists? Then we can have these filters, Today, This week, etc. to help users to preview a set of specific lists.